# how process comma separated parameter passed by angular in spring boot API

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am using angular 6 as front end. Using front end input I want to know the status of tracking id 3,5,6. How to process this. Below is my code:

Angular service code:

```js
getConsignmentByTrackingid(trackingid): Observable<any> {
    console.log(trackingid);
    //tracking ids are : 3,5,6
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/trackingid/${trackingid}`);
}
```

Spring boot controller code:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/tracking_history/trackingid/{trackingid}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tracking>> findByTrackingId(@PathVariable String trackingid){
 try{
        List<Tracking> trackings = trackingRepository.findByTrackingId(trackingid);
        if (trackings.isEmpty())
        {
          return new ResponseEntity<List<Tracking>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
          //return new ResponseEntity<>(trackings, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);              
        }
        //System.out.println(trackings);
        //output of system.out.println is : 3,5,6.
        //How can I return these numbers one by one
        return new ResponseEntity<>(trackings, HttpStatus.OK);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Don't use request param, use query param instead

Answer (score 0):

IMO if you need to send data in the form of array or object then you should not use query parmas or params in the HTTP.

In this case Request type should be `POST/PUT` and you should pass the data in the body part like below -

```
http.post(url, {body: setOfIds})
```

Comment: Good suggestion!!! but my problem is how to process that object which contains 3,5,6 and return one by one in spring boot controller

Comment: If you want to pass one by one you can iterate over the array of IDs, and fire indvidual request for the ID, but again this is not recommended approach. Sorry I am not well aware about spring boot.